# Custom Authentication Middleware for Standalone Openstack Cinder Service

Tags: authentication, openstack, cinder, openstack-cinder, openstack-keystone

I am trying to build a standalone cinder service. I would like to build a custom authentication middleware and use that instead of Keystone. 
Does anyone know of any blog posts, articles, etc. that documents the process of building custom authentication and using it with an Openstack service?